# security of mysql socket on shared server

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets, security

if a server has multiple websites, how secure is mysql client/server communication?

```
ls -la /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Dec 27 20:34 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Does it mean every user/web_process can sniff socket and possibly delete the socket file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean every user/web_process can sniff socket and possibly delete the socket file?

No.

With regard to the first: Being able to access the socket file only lets a process make their own connection to the server. It doesn't grant them any access to other connections. (Just like a normal network socket -- any number of users can connect to a network server, but that doesn't mean they can see each other's traffic.)

For the second: Deleting a file on a UNIX system requires write access to the folder it's in. (With some special exceptions for directories with the sticky bit set, which isn't the case here.) The `/var/run/mysqld` directory is typically only writable by the MySQL user.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting or more technically unlinking files is an operation done on the the directory, not the file.  Same with "sniffing", if by that you mean discovering the file.  That all depends on directory permissions.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html

In this case, those permissions mean anyone can connect to MySQL through the socket.  Pretty standard for MySQL sockets to leave the security to the MySQL auth side.  So is that socket location, so there's very little guessing to be done by anyone who wants to find it.